# Right click on Eclipse "Project Explorer" doesn't change focus

Tags: android, eclipse

I'll start by saying that everything was fine until I had some system problems a couple of days ago and my machine froze.  A reset corrected that, and then I upgraded my VMWare, which insisted that I bring Eclipse down first.  Not sure which of those screwed things up.

I'm in the source panel editing the source for an Android project.  I save, then right click the project in the Project Explorer panel expecting to select Run As and pick the run mode.  Instead, the Panel Explorer doesn't take focus before popping up the menu, so I get "Run Configurations" only.  Also, I can't double click a source file and pop it up without first clicking the Project Explorer panel header first to switch the focus.

Anyone seen this before? I'm guessing there's some setting file that got corrupted.  The interruption in workflow is driving me nuts.  Help!

Comment: Just re-install eclipse.

Comment: There has *got* to be a better way than burning it down and starting over.

Comment: I agree, there is probably a better way.  But my experience is like yours here... crickets.  So scorching the earth is most likely faster.

Comment: Okay, I wish I could withdraw my question.  Here's what appears to have happened.  Like I said, I upgraded VMWare, and the problem started shortly after that.  It wasn't until today, though, when I couldn't get my machine to recognize my printer when I turned it on, that I decided to reboot.  --  Yeah, I know  --  And when everything came back up, I started up Eclipse and found that, voila, Eclipse was working properly again.  Apparently there's something that VMWare Tools uses that Eclipse also makes use of.  I feel really silly right about now....

Comment: first: restart eclipse window perspective, second: check if there are updates for eclipse and download them, then restart.